# dpkg: error processing package libc6:amd64 (--configure):

Tags: upgrade

Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

`sudo apt update` - OK

`sudo apt upgrade` - produces the following:

```
Need to get 0 B/45.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 87.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up libc6:amd64 (2.31-0ubuntu9.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libc6:amd64.postinst: 193: sleep: not found
dpkg: error processing package libc6:amd64 (--configure):
 installed libc6:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: `sleep: not found` suggests something messed up with your coreutils package. What happens if you type `/bin/sleep 1` at the command line?

Comment: root@JANDMSCOMP:/home/johnbunix# /bin/sleep 1
bash: /bin/sleep: No such file or directory

Comment: So the first thing I would try is re-installing the coreutils package i.e. `sudo apt install --reinstall coreutils` (of course, that may fail for the same reasons - let's see)

Comment: Yes you are right it failed again for the same reason:   Setting up libc6:amd64 (2.31-0ubuntu9.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libc6:amd64.postinst: 193: sleep: not found
dpkg: error processing package libc6:amd64 (--configure):
 installed libc6:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: OK so you're going to need to get creative. Is `busybox` available on your system? Does `busybox sleep 1` work?

Comment: Yes busybox is available on my system. 'busybox sleep 1' appears to work since there are no errors produced.

Comment: OK so let's see if you can bootstrap it: `sudo ln -s busybox /bin/sleep` and **then** try `sudo apt install --reinstall coreutils`

Comment: That worked! I was able to reinstall coreutils and all my packages are up-to-date. Thank you steeldriver. Now onto the next problem...